# Auto-suggestion of which SE site I should post my question in

Tags: feature-request, questions, scope

Sometimes, I have a random question popping in my head, but I'm not sure whether there is any SE where the question will be on topic. Now that we have so many SE websites, it's quite trouble some to visually find it [in the list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

I am thinking whether it will be a good idea to have a feature where I can enter my question (probably in stackexchange.com domain) and the website will suggest what websites may be good fits based on keywords or other analysis.

I'm not sure how technically feasible it is, but I think it will be a very useful addition, especially as the number of sites is growing.

Answer (score 6):

That isn't a good idea, because actual human beings have trouble correctly identifying whether a site would be a good fit for their question. Relegating the task to a computer can only lead to poorer decisions. What's worse, people can then claim, "But Stack Exchange told me to post my question here, so it can't be off topic".

The best way to know if a site is the right place for your question is to look at other questions on the site. If I'm not sure whether Stack Exchange has a site relating to the subject of my question, I usually use a search engine to find related keywords on a Stack Exchange site.